# Moving every value in a certain to a certain cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of contacts with over 4000 rows. Problem is every ID per person has been duplicated, each duplicated row stores the alternate contact details such mobile, work phone. What i need to do is make the unique 1d's in one column by the subsequent work, work2, home 2, mobile, mobile 2 etc on the same row rather it being below.

I was wondering if there was a way of doing, for every value in the work 2  telephone type, move to father work cell being (I2) in the screenshot.

As cut and pasting every cell to put them into their designated cells is to time consuming

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array formula with `INDEX` and `MATCH`. This example is for the Mother Work column - and I'm guessing that the actual phone number would be in the P column.

`=INDEX($P:$P,MATCH($C2&N$1,$C:$C&$H:$H,0))`

Make sure to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER , instead of just ENTER to commit the formula - since it needs to be an array formula to work.

If you put this formula in N2, it will look for something with the ID in C2 and the text from N1 in Column C and Column H, respectively - and return the value from column P of the matching row.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would transpose your data, it creates a dummy column that count main id and which rows to delete.

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub TransposeData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cl As Variant
Dim count As Long
Dim cel As Range
Dim delRng As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set worksheet name

ws.Cells(1, 20).Value = "DelRC" 'dummy Column
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row
Set myRange = Range(ws.Cells(2, 8), ws.Cells(lrow, 8)) 'Loop range


For Each cl In myRange 'Loop through range
    If ws.Cells(cl.Row - 1, 3).Value = ws.Cells(cl.Row, 3).Value Then 'Check id - 1 = id
        ws.Cells(cl.Row, 20).Value = 1 'Print dummy
    ElseIf ws.Cells(cl.Row - 1, 3).Value <> ws.Cells(cl.Row, 3).Value Then 'Check id - 1 <> id
        count = ws.Cells(cl.Row, 3).Row 'Store first id location
    End If
    If ws.Cells(cl.Row, 19).Value <> "Home" Then 'Home = skip loop
        Select Case ws.Cells(cl.Row, 19).Value 'Check value
        Case "Work" 'Work -> paste to Mother Work
            ws.Cells(count, 14).Value = ws.Cells(cl.Row, 8).Value 'Copy and paste
        Case "Work2" 'Work2 -> paste to Father Work
            ws.Cells(count, 9).Value = ws.Cells(cl.Row, 8).Value 'Copy and paste
        Case "Mobile" 'Mobile -> paste to Mother Mobile
            ws.Cells(count, 13).Value = ws.Cells(cl.Row, 8).Value 'Copy and paste
        Case "Mobile2" 'Mobile2 -> paste to Father Mobile
            ws.Cells(count, 14).Value = ws.Cells(cl.Row, 8).Value 'Copy and paste
        End Select
    End If
Next cl
Set myRange = myRange.Offset(0, 12)
For Each cel In myRange
    If cel.Value = 1 Then
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = cel
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(delRng, cel)
        End If
    End If
Next cel
If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete 'Delete dummy column and all rows = 1
ws.Cells(1, 20).Value = ""
End Sub
```